# Is removing fragments from ViewPager and adding new ones a good idea in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i am looking for a second opinion. I have a class that extends the Fragment class and contains a ViewPager and MaterialTabs. I need to find a workaround on a problem and I would like to remove tabs from ViewPager and add just one (fragment too) and so on.

[image]

For instance, i start with two tabs and on an action i want to remove those tabs and add a new one and on a different action to re-add those two tabs. 
Is this plain stupid or it has a shot? Thank you.

Below is my class that i will work on:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTab;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost;
import it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabListener;

/**
 *
 */
public class PuzzlesTabActivity extends Fragment implements MaterialTabListener {

    public static int NUM_TABS = 2;
    public static boolean currentlyRunning;
    private MaterialTabHost tabHost;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private PuzzlesTabActivity.ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(layout.puzzle_tab_layout, container, false);

        if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(this.getActivity())) {
            this.tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) rootView.findViewById(id.myTabHost);
            this.pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(id.myPager);
            try {
                this.pager.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);

                // init view pager
                this.adapter = new PuzzlesTabActivity.ViewPagerAdapter(this.getActivity().getFragmentManager());
                this.pager.setAdapter(this.adapter);
                this.pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
                        PuzzlesTabActivity.this.tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                    }
                });
                this.pager.setCurrentItem(0);

                // add tabs
                for (int i = 0; i < this.adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                    this.tabHost.addTab(this.tabHost.newTab().setText(this.adapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.startActivity(this.getActivity(), new Intent(this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class), null);
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
        this.pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {

    }

    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        public Fragment getItem(int num) {
            switch (num) {
                case 0:
                    PuzzlesFragment aFragment = new PuzzlesFragment();
                    return aFragment;
                case 1:
                    FavFragment nFragment = new FavFragment();
                    return nFragment;
                default:
                    return new PuzzlesFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PuzzlesTabActivity.NUM_TABS;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return PuzzlesTabActivity.this.getResources().getString(string.new_puzzles);
                case 1:
                    return PuzzlesTabActivity.this.getResources().getString(string.fav_puzzles);
                default:
                    return PuzzlesTabActivity.this.getResources().getString(string.new_puzzles);
            }
        }
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Utils.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("lastActivity", this.getClass().getName());
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        PuzzlesTabActivity.currentlyRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        PuzzlesTabActivity.currentlyRunning = false;
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. ViewPager already does something like this in a normal use case. It works by creating the fragment to the left, the current fragment, and the fragment to the right, as you swipe (so only three exist at a time).

As for adding and removing the tabs, that is fine to do as well. Just make sure to handle swapping for the new tab's fragment in the ViewPager.

Comment: Thank you. Will document a bit and try.